# Context menu does not show over a SpriteView in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, spriteview

I'm unable to show a context menu over a `SpriteView` in `SwiftUI` on a mac.  I am able to show a context menu not over it -- right click on the blue works, on red doesn't, see image.

However, I also need to be able to pan the scene in the view, so `mouseDragged()` inside the scene must work.  Placing an `overlay()` on top of the view blocks mouse dragging events from propagating down to the scene.

Xcode 13.2, deployment 12.2, Swift 5

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteView

func MenuItem(_ text: String, _ action: @escaping ()->Void) -> some View {
    Button {
        action()
    } label: {
        Text(text)
    }
}

var scene : SKScene {
    
    let r = SKScene.init(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))

    r.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    r.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    r.backgroundColor = .red
    
    return r
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SpriteView.init(scene: scene)
                .padding()
                .contextMenu {
                    MenuItem("1 Preferences ...") {
                    }
                }

        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .contextMenu {
            MenuItem("0 Preferences ...") {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to add transparent overlay and attach context menu there, like

```
SpriteView.init(scene: scene)
    .padding()
    .overlay(
        Color.clear
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .contextMenu {               // << here !!
                MenuItem("1 Preferences ...") {
                }
            }
    )
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.5

[image: demo]

Comment: Works but then mouse dragging the scene inside the SpriteView doesn't work.

Comment: You would said that before ;) ... actually that's the reason - conflict of gestures.

Comment: Context menu is invoked with mouse right-click, but drag is with left-click, there must be a way to filter this out

Comment: I need mouse dragging to pan the scene.  I need context menu over the view.  A work around might be doable with onChange(of:) inside the view of a variable inside the scene which gets set when a right-click is detected inside the scene.  It's ugly though.